# How to display a div on selecting a dropdown option

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I am creating a form where I have a dropdown list 
when user selects the option

> **Software developer**

a new div is displayed , with two option

> 1. App Developer
> 2. Web Developer

I am giving code below -:

html code -

```html
<div class="form-group">
         <label for="dept"> Departmant </label>
         <select id="dept" (change)="fun()" class="form-control" class="form-control" name="departmant" [(ngModel)]="departmant">
           <option value="1"> HelpDesk </option>
           <option value="2"> Hr</option>
           <option value="3"> Software Engineer </option>
           <option value="4"> System Admin </option>
        </select>
         </div>

<div class="form-group" *ngIf="doninSe">
        <label for="domin"> Domain: </label>
        <select id="domin" class="form-control" name="domin" [(ngModel)]="domin">
          <option *ngFor="let domins of Domin"> {{domins.name}}  </option>
        </select>
</div>
```

ts code -:

```ts
export class CreateEmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
  DominSe: boolean = True ;

constructor() { }

  Domin: Departmants[] =
                   [{id: 1 , name: 'App Developer' },
                    {id: 2 , name: 'Web Developer'},
                  ];


  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Also I am getting error while defining DomineSe variable

```
DominSe: boolean = True ;
```

getting error -:

```
[ts] Cannot find name 'True'.
any
```

Comment: Use true instead True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

boolean value should be **true** not `True` and also use the same variable name in **html** as you declared in `.ts`

here's is example

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="dominSe">
     <label for="domin"> Domain: </label>
     <select id="domin" class="form-control" name="domin" [(ngModel)]="domin">
         <option *ngFor="let domins of Domin"> {{domins.name}}  </option>
      </select>
</div>
```

and in `.ts`

```
dominSe: boolean = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

should be `true`

```
DominSe: boolean = true;
```